# Fastest way to move file inside the same panel

Tags: far-manager

Let's say I'm on the right panel now in some folder. I have this hierarchy in the folder:

```
- Folder1
|
- File1
```

I want to move `File1` into `Folder1`. What I always do in such cases is:

1. Copy current path `Shift + Alt + Insert`
2. Go to the left panel `Tab`
3. Run `cd` with copied path.
4. Go to `Folder1`
5. Go to the right panel.
6. Move File1(from the right panel) to the open Folder1 on the left.

It's a lot of actions and I want to optimize this process.

How can I do this?

Ideally, it would be great to do this inside only right panel and don't change anything on the left.

Answer (score 2):

1. Select the file to move and press <kbd>F6</kbd>.
2. Type `./` followed by the first few letters of the target folder and FM will autocomplete, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to perform the move.

Comment: You don't even need to type `./`. I start directly typing the folder name, in this case `Folder1`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the old good command line.  That's my main reason for using Far that unless Windows's own File Explorer, Far can handle the command line. So type `move` `space`  copy the file name (Ctrl-Enter on the file)`space`  copy the folder name  (Ctrl-Enter on the folder)

Answer (score 0):

One more solution I like more than autocomplete because it is faster for me than additional step to verify that you selected a right thing in autocomplete list.

I want to move File1 into Folder1:

- Be sure you do not select any files/folder by key INS.
- the active cursor should be located on folder.

1. Click **Ctrl+Ins** (copy folder name info clipboard)
2. Move cursor on file
3. Click **F6** then **Shift+Ins**, then Enter.